# Is it possible to disable caching from Django admin pages?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-admin

**[additional information]**

I asked for a way to disable caching site-wide. **This is probably overkill**, because all I need is a way to be able to **see the most recent version of a page**, when either the database or the program to generate it has been modified.

There is a strong consensus that **modifying settings at runtime is a very bad idea**.

So, some ideas: **clearing the cache** could work, as would **sending a flag** to specify that I don't want to see a cached version, or specifying that **requests from my IP address shouldn't see cached pages**.

**[original question]**

I have a Django-based website at [ozake.com](https://ozake.com), and I frequently rewrite parts of the programming or change page content.

Each time I work on it, I **modify settings.py to disable caching** so I can see my modifications in real time.

When I'm done, I re-enable caching.

I am using **file-based caching**. Here is the relevant part of settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {'BACKEND':
 #'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
  'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
  'LOCATION': '/var/www/mysite.com/cache',
```

When I work on the site I comment out the last two lines and uncomment the dummy cache line.

This means SSH'ing into the site, modifying settings.py, working on the site, then re-modifying it.

**Is there any way I can make this into a check box somewhere in /admin with admin.py?**

Comment: I am starting to think that I need to just maintain a separate site for development.

Comment: maybe place a script (shell) on the machine where your site is deployed, on a certain action that script gets executed and modifies the settings file?

Comment: Maybe using django-constance to set a dynamic boolean flag from the admin, then create a custom cache backend which behaves like DummyCache or FileBasedCache according to the flag value ?

Comment: Long shot, but https://github.com/jazzband/django-configurations gives you the opportunity to use environment variables as values in django settings. You could possibly create a button in the admin that changes the environment variable and restarts the server.

Comment: "I am starting to think that I need to just maintain a separate site for development."—You really, *really* should. Or, actually, you need to [maintain a separate site for _production_, since your current "production" site is really a development site](https://twitter.com/stahnma/status/634849376343429120).

Comment: What's your specific reason for disabling the cache when you're in the admin? Is it simply so you can modify some data and see the changes immediately? Are there specific views / objects / etc. that you're concerned with?

Comment: My own site, Ozake.com, is hosted along with several of my clients' sites on a single server. Right now, when I update pages, I don't see changes right away because of caching. That makes it frustrating to edit the content. I would like to be able to temporarily disable caching while I'm modifying pages. It may be that a better approach would be to signal to the caching system that the page has been modified.  I should probably ask that in a separate question.

Comment: If you just want to invalidate the whole cache at will, you might create a trivial view which does `from django.core.cache import cache; cache.clear()`, and invoke it via "hidden" url

Comment: Can your write that as an answer? It seems like a good choice. Perhaps I could add an argument to call the view, so that ozake.com/about?cc would clear the cache.

Comment: Sure ! Please note I already posted a solution to your original question which does not require to modify settings at run-time. That might still be overkill in your use case, but could be easily extended to switch between different caching strategies. I'ld like to here your comment on that, as your question has been much inspirational, and for myself the motivation to look deeply into the Django cache framework ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to invalidate the whole cache at will, you might create a trivial view which does that:

file `views.py`:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def clear_cache(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise PermissionDenied
    cache.clear()
    return HttpResponse('Cache has been cleared')
```

file `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('clear_cache/', views.clear_cache),
]
```

then invoke it with your browser:

```
http://HOST/clear_cache
```

Comment: I will modify the solution slightly… the thought of having an unprotected address that  affects caching makes me shiver. The technique is just what I needed though. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome ! As a side note: the view is already protected against unauthorized access - if the user issuing the request is not a superuser, an exception is thrown and no caching is affected at all

Comment: So I could just add this to the regular default view, and super users would always get the most recent version. I don't need the URL. It's funny how much simpler things can become when you have more knowledge.

Comment: I understand your point ... but while this might seem convenient, you also loose a little bit of control. First, please note that when the superuser goes to the "default page" all users are affected, since the cache is invalidated system-wide. Second, you always get cache invalidation every time you invoke the default view (and never when you work with other views) even when unnecessary. This sounds much like an uncontrolled side effect. Even if it's not a big deal in this case, it not the safest solution either ...

Comment: ... I'm still convinced that a specific url for cache invalidation is more appropriate an effective. Open a new tab in the browser with that address, work with your site contents, and when you're done with editing refresh the "clear_cache page" ... it's that simple ;)

Comment: It turns out there's a problem with this answer: the address itself is cached. If you come back to it a second time, you will see the message "Cache has been cleared", but in fact nothing will have happened. I ended up adding a flag that I can assign to random values (see my final solution below). Thanks again!

Comment: Good catch @AndrewSwift ... I updated the code adding "never_cache" decorator to the view, to instruct the browser not to cache this page. Could you confirm if this helps ?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Would it be possible to write something like "if request.user.is_superuser: @never_cache" before (or in) the view definition?

Comment: In principle it could be possible by selectively calling add_never_cache_headers() explicitly instead of using the never_cache decorator. However, that would be tricky as you could invoke the url as anonymous user, and later invoke it again as superuser,  but at that point the browser had already been instructed to cache the page.
On the other side, there is no real benefit in caching such a simple page, so all in all I think it's not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def PageView(request):
    ...
    if request.GET.get('clear') == 'cache':
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            title = request.GET.get('flag') + ' ' + title 
            cache.clear()
    ...
    return render(request, template, context)
```

So now I can go to **https://ozake.com/en/home?clear=cache&flag=sdf**

And the cache will be cleared (if I am logged in to the admin pages).

Two notes:

1. *This address* will be cached, so **it is necessary to change the flag string** each time, to clear the cache.
2. **The flag is added to the page title** so you can be sure you are seeing the most recent version.

Comment: Obviously, the flag being added to the title is specific to my CMS program.

Comment: You can go one step further and place this url inside one of the `ModelAdmin`s using `get_urls()` and wraping it in `admin_view()` so that this function is only accessible to logged in Admin users.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate site for development is always a Very Good Thing.
Still, having the possibility to easily disable caching on the production site might bring some additional benefits:

- to investigate subtle bugs related to caching
- to measure effective performance gain with real production data

I do believe this can be successfully solved with a small amount of code providing a thin custom caching backend.

Basically:

- Django instantiates a cache "default" object once at startup, treating it as a singleton, and uses it forever
- In our custom cache backend, we will keep an internal instance of two separates objects (a "dummy" and a "file based" cache) and expose only one of them throuh the required inteface methods
- This way, we are actually acting as a class proxy to either FileBasedCache or DummyCache
- We can easily control which object is active with a variable, thus switching the behaviour at run-time, with no need to restart Django

The following POC has been checked in a small test project with positive results.

First, write the "proxy" class which behaves either as FileBasedCache or DummyCache:

file 'project/mycache.py':

```
from django.core.cache.backends.filebased import FileBasedCache
from django.core.cache.backends.dummy import DummyCache
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from constance import config


class MyCache(DummyCache):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dummy_cache = DummyCache(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file_cache = FileBasedCache(*args, **kwargs)

    def _active_cache(self):
        """
        Select either DummyCache or FileBasedCache based on configuration
        """
        return self.file_cache if config.CACHING_ENABLED else self.dummy_cache

    def add(self, key, value, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None):
        return self._active_cache().add(key, value, timeout, version)

    def get(self, key, default=None, version=None):
        return self._active_cache().get(key, default, version)

    def set(self, key, value, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None):
        self._active_cache().set(key, value, timeout, version)

    def touch(self, key, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None):
        return self._active_cache().touch(key, timeout, version)

    def delete(self, key, version=None):
        self._active_cache().delete(key, version)

    def has_key(self, key, version=None):
        return self._active_cache().has_key(key, version)

    def clear(self):
        self._active_cache().clear()
```

and reference it in project's settings as follows:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'project.mycache.MyCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/www/mysite.com/cache,
    }
}
```

Please note that the actual actions are delegated to one of the two internal objects, according to the current value of **config.CACHING_ENABLED**. No caching logic has been re-implemented in the proxy model.

Finally, to control the switching flag from the admin (the easy part) define a boolean value 'CACHING_ENABLED' for **django-constance** (a popular app which provides an Admin interface to edit dynamic settings).

Add this to the project's settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'constance',
    'constance.backends.database',
]

CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHING_ENABLED': (True, 'Set to False to disable caching'),
}
```

then:

```
pip install django-constance[database]
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This looks like a solid solution but I don't have the time or expertise to put it to use right now. I'll come back to it when I'm further along in the overall project and need a more robust solution. I'm really very inexperienced at Django and anyone who looked at my project would probably cringe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [django-admin-caching](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-caching/) module. First to install it type this in your bash terminal:

```sh
pip install django-admin-caching
```

After it is installed, you add this piece of code to your `settings.py` so that it auto-registers itself:

```py
settings.INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #...
   'django_admin_caching',
   #...
]
```

This should enable caching on your django admin page.

Comment: It looks like this is for caching the admin pages, not the main site. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score -1):

For the main request, you can use [cache-table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#createcachetable).

An alternative is to use middleware comparing the IP that receives the request with your specific IP, that you can store in your settings. Something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
def get_user_ip(request):
    client_address = request.META['HTTPS_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
    if your_ip == client_address:
        save_user_ip()
```